# Convert longitude and latitude to find northing and easting value using PHP

Tags: php

I have loop that gives me a longitude and latitude for each client , I am looking for a function where I can pass these variables into and it will find out northing and easting value.

I have tried gPoint class but no joy.

```
Foreach ($clients as $client)
{
    $client[lat];
    $client[lon;];
    Function convert($lat,$long)
}
```

Comment: This does not seems to be a correct way of writing php code. no semicolons ? function reference inside foreach? whyy???

Comment: please share your exact PHP code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

There's no native function in PHP that can help you. But you can use this: [gpoint](https://gist.github.com/duedal/840476)

Example:

```
<?php
$gpoint = new gPoint();
$gpoint->setLatLong($lat,$long);
$gpoint->convertLLtoLCC();

echo 'Northing and easting value: '. $gpoint->lccN() . ' ' . $gpoint->lccE();
```